# How to exclude Jupyter notebook checkpoints from git

Tags: python, git, jupyter-notebook, gitignore

My .gitignore file is as follows:

```
.ipynb_checkpoints
*/.ipynb_checkpoints/*
```

But when I do git status, I still get checkpoints being tracked.

```
C:\python_git\python3>git status
On branch main
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/main'.

    Changes not staged for commit:
      (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
      (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
            modified:   Lists/.ipynb_checkpoints/List Basic Operations-checkpoint.ipynb
            modified:   Lists/List Basic Operations.ipynb
    
    Untracked files:
      (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
            .gitignore
    
    no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

Comment: `.ipynb_checkpoints/` with the `/` works for me

Comment: `git rm -r --cached Lists/.ipynb_checkpoints`